# With yesod, how can one send defaultLayout with a custom HTTP status code?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I've tried the following:

```
sendResponseStatus status403 $ (defaultLayout [whamlet|Foo|] :: Handler Html)
```

Which gives me this type error:

```
<interactive>:1:1: Warning:
    Could not deduce (ToTypedContent (Handler Html))
      arising from a use of ‘sendResponseStatus’
    from the context (MonadHandler m)
      bound by the inferred type of it :: MonadHandler m => m a
      at <interactive>:1:1
    In the expression: sendResponseStatus status403
    In the expression:
      sendResponseStatus status403
      $ (defaultLayout
           ((asWidgetT . toWidget)
              ((blaze-markup-0.7.0.3:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText
                . Data.Text.pack)
                 "Foo")) ::
           Handler Html)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `sendResponseStatus` is not expecting `Handler Html`, but plain `Html` works instead:

```
html <- defaultLayout [whamlet|Foo|]
sendResponseStatus status403 html
```

Which compiles and executes as expected for me.

It may also make sense to encapsulate this logic as such:

```
sendResponseStatusHandler :: (ToTypedContent c, MonadHandler m) => Status -> m c -> m b
sendResponseStatusHandler status handler = do
  response <- handler
  sendResponseStatus status response
```

Since being able to pass in a `Handler` seems quite a bit more powerful to me.